# Cannot convert Argument 1 from WCHAR to const char *

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode

I need help: Visual Studio 2019 says that it `Cannot convert Argument 1 from WCHAR to const char *`

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
                    CloseHandle(hSnap);
                    return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
```

What does this mean? Is there an obvious error in the code?

Comment: Which line is giving this error?

Comment: If you are dealing with `wchar_t*` you should instead use [`std::wcscmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscmp)

Comment: I find it good that you asked this question instead of the practice of silencing the warning with a cast which many new programmers do only to find out later that it either crashes or does not work.

Comment: It would appear that you are compiling your file with the "Use UNICODE Character Set" option selected for the project: this will redefine the `MODULEENTRY32` type to a `MODULEENTRY32W` structure, in which the `szModule` member is a `WCHAR` array. Is it viable for you to switch your project settings to "Use Multibyte Character Set?" If not, you will have to work on your code so that the argument for your function is also a `WCHAR` string, or provide code to convert it, as you can't compare (directly) a `char*` string to a `wchar_t*` string.

Comment: @CoryKramer But then `modName` will also need to be a `wchar_t*` string.

Comment: if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {

Answer (score 2):

Consider this line from your code snippet:

> ```
> if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
> ```

`modEntry` is an instance of the `MODULEENTRY32` structure. In Unicode builds (which is the default setting in Visual Studio since VS2005), this structure is `#define`'d in the Windows SDK headers as `MODULEENTRY32W` (note the ending **W**).

If you read [the MSDN documentation on `MODULEENTRY32W`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-moduleentry32w), you'll find that its `szModule` field is a `WCHAR` array. This means that the module name is represented using a *Unicode* UTF-16-encoded string, which follows the Unicode build settings I mentioned above. `WCHAR` is basically a `typedef` meaning `wchar_t`.

On the other hand, the `strcmp` function you invoke takes as input two `char`-based (`const char*`) strings to compare, not a `WCHAR`-based string and a `char`-based one. So, the compiler correctly complains because of this type mismatch.

To fix this problem, I would suggest you to move your code to Unicode. Basically, you can pass a `const wchar_t*` string as input, instead of `const char*`:

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const wchar_t* modName) {
```

and you can use the Unicode-based `wcscmp` function to compare the strings, instead of `strcmp`:

```
if (!wcscmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
```

An alternative would be changing your project settings and switch to ANSI/MBCS builds (in the VS2019 IDE select your project `Properties | Advanced | Character Set` and pick `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`), but I would prefer fixing your code to make it Unicode-based.

Note that you need to use the `L` prefix for `wchar_t`-based string literals in your code, e.g. `L"Some Unicode UTF-16 string"`.

---

Another option would be to convert the Unicode `MODULEENTRY32::szModule` string to ANSI using an [ATL conversion helper like `CW2A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cw2aex-class?view=vs-2019) at the `strcmp` call site:

```
#include <atlconv.h> // for CW2A
...

// CW2A converts from wchar_t-string to char-string
if (!strcmp(CW2A(modEntry.szModule), modName)) {
```

but note that this Unicode-to-ANSI conversion can be bug-prone, as Unicode is a super-set of ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling your project for Unicode, and you are using the `TCHAR` variant of `MODULEENTRY32`, `Module32First()`, and `Module32Next()`, so they are going to map to their Unicode variants, not their ANSI variants.  As such, the `modEntry.szModule` will be a `WCHAR[]`, which you can't pass to `strcmp()`.

You are looking for a module using an ANSI string, so you should be using the ANSI variant of the Win32 API functions.

You are also leaking the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` if a matching module is not found.

Try this instead:

```cpp
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32A modEntry; // <-- note the trailing A !
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32FirstA(hSnap, &modEntry)) { // <-- note the trailing A !
            do {
                if (strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName) == 0) {
                    CloseHandle(hSnap);
                    return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }
            } while (Module32NextA(hSnap, &modEntry)); // <-- note the trailing A !
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap); // <-- add this !
     }
```

Comment: How do I put my code into Unicode

Comment: Change `modName` to use `wchar_t` instead of `char`, change the API references to use their `W` version instead of their `A` version, and change `strcmp()` to `wcscmp()`. If you can't change `modName` to `wchar_t`, you can at least use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent to convert its data to `wchar_t` at runtime before then comparing that converted data to `modEntry.szModule`